# How do Java SE applications run as services on my windows NT server

Tags: java, windows-services

I have few questions

1) Our Applications uses Jini2.0.02 
(http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jini)
Jini is a distributed network system where it can make other java services talk each other.

My question is how these java services are present in the List of Windows "Services".
Our applications are developed in java1.4.2_04.

2) Java EE applications run on application servers like Tomcat, JBoss, etc where we need to build an EAR for deploying web applications.

My question here is; in what format( jar/war/ear) should I need to build Java SE applications?
Will there be any application servers to deploy Java SE applications to?

Comment: 1) I guess a process wrapper 2) Eh?  War/Ear/Jar etc are just zip files with a different extension.  WAR=Web, EAR=Enterprise and JAR=Java Application aRchive.  You generally build them with a build tool such as Ant or Maven but you can hand-crank them from zip files.  I'm not quite sure what the question is.

Comment: 1) Perhaps your apps use the Java Service Wrapper. 2) Ditto to what Dan says. The J2EE server should be able to deploy the war or ear.

Answer (score 0):

1) If you google "Java Service Wrapper", you may find something interesting.

2) What do you mean "Java SE applications"? Are they only some jar files? They can be run directly from command line by "java -jar app.jar". WAR and EAR are the formats for Java EE application deploy package for the Java EE application servers.